# How to add a tkinter program in React app

Tags: python, reactjs, web, tkinter, portfolio

So I have a portfolio website (built on react and node) and a Tkinter program python (of a game).
And I want to display the tkinter program on the website so people can play it without downloading or anything.
How can I do that?

Comment: **short answer**: you can't do that; **a possible solution** (doesn't mean it is good): have server hardware connected to display, display the tkinter window on it, take screenshots, send them to the client (still need to use js to send user input), also you can only have so many games on the screen at a time (could alter between windows and stuff but still this is a horrible solution); **even more horrible solution**: write python interpreter in js that supporst `tkinter`; **conclusion**: just post screenshots of the game or create a simple demo version in js

Comment: Yea that is just not worth it.

Comment: FYI, trinket.io have a special virtual machine on their servers that supports tkinter (and pygame). See https://trinket.io/features/pygame

Comment: easy solution : start Xvfb with openbox and x11vnc on a machine. use x11vnc -id to let vnc render only thewindow of the tkinter app, in react make a window and show the vnc output. one can also use novnc with apache proxy and proxyreverse settings so the vnc is tunneled through port 443 by using websockify